# d3js proper use of selectAll and dataSet

Tags: d3.js

I used the following example
http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data/
to start with d3js.
But I can not manage to make this code work

```
   <script>
    var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];
    var dataset2 = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];
    d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text("New paragraph!");

    d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data(dataset2)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text("New paragraph23!");
    </script>
```

> It still shows only one set of data.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to separate the datasets by class.

```js
var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];
var dataset2 = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];
d3.select("body").selectAll(".set1")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("p")
.attr("class", "set1")
.text("New paragraph!");

d3.select("body").selectAll(".set2")
.data(dataset2)
.enter()
.append("p")
.attr("class", "set2")
.text("New paragraph23!");
```

```html
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```